# Woocommerce API Error 100 Invalid JSON Returned

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I'm loading product information automatically through the woocommerce V2 product api.  It works fine for the most part, but the odd time I will get a "100" "Invalid JSON Returned" even on identical calls.
Its intermittent and it doesn't provide any more information then that.  I've checked the JSON args and they are identical to ones that work.  I've validated the JSON syntax, no issues.  If I run the same thing again, sometimes it loads without that error.

Not sure if anyone has seen this before and can provide insight?

Comment: I just wanted to note that anyone having this problem.  It is a time-out issue.  Images can kill a load, especially if you have something like smushit plugins that do more work during the load.   Try to keep your api calls as lean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all intents and purposes this error seems to be directly related to a time out during the load.  It will continue if you are running API calls through a loop.  If you keep track of items not updated, just try again.   Like I said in my comment above, try and keep your actual call as lean as possible.  Lots of images can bog it down, especially if you have image processing plugins smushing stuff etc.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by disabling the "New Images Optimisation" on the SG Optimiser plug in